# Distribution of MDI children in an MDI parent

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mdi

I have an MDI parent form that creates many MDI children at run time. Is there a smart way to evenly ditribute these forms inside there parent? 
any ideas?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
**ArrangeIcons**     child window icons are arranged within the parent
**Cascade**          arrange the child windows within the parent window in a cascaded fashion
**TileHorizontal**   tile the child windows horizontally
**TileVertical**     tile the child windows vertically


//Cascade all child forms.        
this.LayoutMdi(System.Windows.Forms.MdiLayout.Cascade);
```

have a look at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/mdiformstutorial.aspx for a start

Comment: I had to put this.LayoutMdi into protected override void OnShown to get the layout working work http://stackoverflow.com/a/2836353/74585